# Updating session cookie on first request to a site and add to custom header on additional requests

Tags: asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-identity, openiddict

I'm using ASP.NET Identity and [OpenIddict](https://github.com/openiddict/openiddict-core) for a custom authorization server in MVC / Razor Pages. I'm supporting most OpenID flows with OpenIddict and user and admin areas with ASP.NET Identity.

The site is accessed directly from desktop browsers, mobile apps and other projects, especially the endpoints for starting a login and a authroization flow.

Everything is working as expected.

Now I would like to add partial multi-tenancy by only switching CSS based on the tenant. The rest of the app will remain untouched. I was going to start by modifying the `_Styles.cshtml` file by adding the following:

```
@using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http

@inject IHttpContextAccessor accessor

@{
    var ok = accessor.HttpContext.Request.Headers.TryGetValue("X-Tenant-Id", out var values);
    var tenantId = values.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Then depending on the tenant I will add the CSS file.

How, through the whole app, in views and in controller actions there redirects and links to other pages (eg. from login page to register page or forgot password). This is a problem because the custom header above is not persisted in further requests.

So I was thinking of added the header to the session state. Currently I'm not using sessions, but I would be doing something similar to what is described in this [MS Article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-7.0#session-state).

Any request that has the above header will update the session state. As this is an essential cookie but I still have to use cookie consent policy and data protection, is it possible to flag it as essential to avoid cookie consent?

Will the work or is there a better solution?

Answer (score 0):

> Is it possible to flag it as essential to avoid cookie consent

If you marked the session cookie as essential ,you would reveive a cookie name of  `.AspNetCore.Session`

```
builder.Services.AddSession(options =>
    {
        options.Cookie.IsEssential = true;
    })
```

and if  you configured cookieConsent as below

```
builder.Services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(op =>
    {         op.CheckConsentNeeded = _ => true;     
    });
```

you won't receive the cookies which are not marked  as essential

I tried as below:

```
public IActionResult Index()
        {
            HttpContext.Response.Cookies.Append("SomeKey", "SomeValue" ,new CookieOptions() { IsEssential=false});
            HttpContext.Session.SetString("SomeKey", "SomeVal");
            return View();
        }
       
        public IActionResult Privacy()
        {

            string? cookieval;
           
            HttpContext.Request.Cookies.TryGetValue("SomeKey", out cookieval);
            var sessionval=HttpContext.Session.GetString("SomeKey");

            return View();
```

The Result:

[image]